# Error saving a string longer than 1500 bytes in Datastore from Dataflow api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

Dataflow job is throwing this error message when I try to save a very long string: The value of property "myProperty" is longer than 1500 bytes., code=INVALID_ARGUMENT.

There is an error when following Google's [DatastoreWordCount](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/cookbook/DatastoreWordCount.java) sample and saving a string longuer then 1500 bytes.

I know that when using Datastore API, I am able to save strings that are longer than 1500 bytes by saving the property as [com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text). However, There is no alternative in [DatastoreWordCount](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/cookbook/DatastoreWordCount.java) sample or in [DatastoreHelper](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/DatastoreHelper.java) class documentation that could indicate that [Text](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text) type is supported.

Could be a way to save such long strings using that api so that it could be read as [com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text)?

The full error message is as follow:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: The value of property "dalekTestExecutions" is longer than 1500 bytes., code=INVALID_ARGUMENT
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:162)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:284)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext$1.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:508)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn.closeWindow(GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn.java:205)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsAndCombineDoFn.java:192)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:224)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:72)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:287)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:223)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:193)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:160)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can save a string longer than 1500 bytes by excluding the value from indexing:

```
Value longString = Value.newBuilder()
    .setStringValue(...)
    .setExcludeFromIndexes(true)
    .build();
```

If you need compatibility with App Engine's `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text` type, you would also want to set the meaning to 15:

```
Value longString = Value.newBuilder()
    .setStringValue(...)
    .setExcludeFromIndexes(true)
    .setMeaning(15)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

DataStore create index for each property so there is a default limit of 1500 bytes on properties. Now if you need to store data something like big JSON then you can specify that index is not needed for this property in following way:

```
Entity newEntity =
                Entity.newBuilder(key)
                        .set("time", Timestamp.parseTimestamp("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"))
                        .set("message", StringValue.newBuilder(JSON).setExcludeFromIndexes(true).build())
                        .build();
```

This way you will be able to save data of bigger size rather than default limit of 1500 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

To be exact:

```
StringValue.newBuilder(yourString).setExcludeFromIndexes(true).build()
```

Comment: Please add more description to your answer.